# set error messages are not fully visible?

Tags: android

I am using fragment class and set error message in it then i have generate error like rectangle type but i want to show error message like round rectangle what will i do?
for more details see [this link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=75885).

Comment: Include the code and some more information about this issue. You can quote (include the relevant info from) the problem from the link, but don't just put a link and let others open to understand the problem. Edit: and Google's issue tracker is not a correct place to ask how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (editText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
  editText.setError("This field can not be blank", R.drawable.border);
```

It will show popup error message on edittext

for rounded corner, create this border.xml in your drawable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="5dip" />

     <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

   <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@android:color/white" />

 </shape>
```

Comment: How does the above code guarantee the error message will be shown in a round rectangle as the question asks ?

Comment: I may be wrong, but that method doesn't exist. There is setError that takes a Drawable as second argument (and not the int reference to the drawable resource, two very different things), but this shouldn't even compile... And the drawable it takes sets the error icon, not the message background, according to the docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html